# Hide values from passenger/webserver log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, logging, passenger

How to hide certain words let say .. qwerty and 12345 from passenger log (passenger.3000.log) in rails?

Is it possible at all? I just don't want to have my passwords in clear in this file, is there any ways to hide them?

Comment: Please ask your question properly. So that ppl can understand it and can reply in the same context. There might be a chance that you will get answers which is miss understood

Answer (score 1):

There is a configuration called [`filter_parameters`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) you can use to not log a parameter when the name matches one of the configured keywords.

In a new Rails project you can find a default configuration in the `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb` file that contains approximately the following code

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation]
```

Just update the configuration according to your needs.

Comment: Is there any password on passenger , If not please edit question and write it properly

Comment: @ArpitVaishnav I did not ask the question, hence it's not up to me to update the question the user originally asked. The answer is based on the interpretation I gave to his question. If you have any comment about the question, you should ask them on the question not on my answer.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti is it possible to do it "on the fly"? I mean if the passenger is running and suddenly I got new word from database.. so I want to hide it from log.. looks like it will be printed in log at first and only then I will be able to hide it, right? and ... thank you for the answer!

Comment: No, not with Rails. You'll need a different process to handle the log storage.